# What is the difference between "that is mine" and "that would be mine"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *that is mine* and *that would be mine*? For example:

> Whose phone is that? **That is mine**.
>
> Whose phone is that? **That would be mine**.

Comment: The second sentence is just a more polite way to say it.

Comment: It's a little like the "can could" pairing. "Could" means a thing is possible if you choose it. "Can" means a thing is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional "that would be mine" is being used only as a tactful and polite way of saying "that is mine".

Asking "Whose phone is that" has an element of "blame" (someone has lost their phone) so it is not surprising that there is some redundant language that makes the language less direct.  "If you are demanding then I would tell you that it is my phone, but since I'm sure you are too polite...."

It is similar to "I would like..." as a polite and indirect way of saying "I want".

It is normal and idiomatic in speech.